# Unity ADS don't load ad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityads

Here is an example of the code I wrote. `OnInitializationComplete` is executed, it starts loading that does not call any of the `OnUnityAdsFailedToLoad` `OnUnityAdsAdLoaded` methods. From this, I concluded that the download takes a very long time or the listener methods are not called. What to do in such a situation? Everything works fine in unity, it takes a long time to load only on android.

```
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Timer());
    }

    private IEnumerator Timer()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        Advertisement.Initialize("5317868", testMode: true, enablePerPlacementLoad: false, this);
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsAdLoaded(string placementId)
    {
        text.text = "Loaded";
        Advertisement.Show("Interstitial_Android");
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsFailedToLoad(string placementId, UnityAdsLoadError error, string message)
    {
        text.text = "UNLoaded";
    }

    public void OnInitializationComplete()
    {
        text.text = "init done";
        Advertisement.Load("Interstitial_Android", this);
    }

    public void OnInitializationFailed(UnityAdsInitializationError error, string message)
    {
        text.text = "UnINIT";
    }
```

I tried to do it through the coroutine and without it. the result is the same. I also tried without a listener, but in this case, even the initialization fails

Answer (score 0):

Loading an Ad involves a server request so it can take time.

You should probably load it in advance (for example, when your level starts) so it's ready to show when needed.

In `OnUnityAdsAdLoaded` you can just set a bool `m_IsReady = true;`
Then, when you want to show it, you first check `if (m_IsReady) Show(...)`

If it's not ready, you can just skip that placement or avoid showing the option to the user (if it is a rewarded ad).